# Trying to virtualize my Windows 10 install on linux in a dual boot setup

Tags: fedora, windows, virtual-machine, qemu

Currently I am dual booting Windows 10 and linux (fedora 39 with KDE), here both are on separate SDDs. I was hoping to use linux for most things and use Windows 10 for games. But here, I am trying to virtualize Windows 10 instead of having to restart and open Windows 10 every time I want to play games. But it isn't working. My virtualization is turned on and everything is set up.

Firstly, I don't want to use a Virtual Drive or turn my Windows 10 installation into a Virtual Drive. Secondly, my Windows 10 and linux EFI partitions are on each of the separate SDDs instead on being on one.

Things I have tried:

1. https://opensource.com/article/21/1/virtualbox-windows-linux
2. https://simgunz.org/posts/2021-12-12-boot-windows-partition-from-linux-kvm/

Using the first method, when the VM the starts, it gets stuck on the "Booting from Hard Disk..." screen and using the second method, when trying "Step 3 - Write a BCD entry on the UEFI boot menu", I get stuck on step 5 as it for some reason cannot copy the BSD entries.

I can reinstall linux if necessary as this install of linux is very new with almost no files but not the Windows 10 install.